# Unhandled Exception Still Crashes Application After Being Caught

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, exception, unhandled-exception

I have a WPF application that consists of multiple projects that have forms, classes, base classes, etc..

Because of the large code base I want to make sure if an exception does happen I can catch it, notify the user and let the application continue without crashing. I understand the pros and cons to doing this.

In the App.xaml.cs of the application I have:

```
private void OnApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += CurrentOnDispatcherUnhandledException;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
    Dispatcher.UnhandledException += DispatcherOnUnhandledException;
    UI.Views.Windows.MainWindow.Show();
}

private void DispatcherOnUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs dispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TEST 3");
}

private void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TEST 2");
}

private void CurrentOnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs dispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TEST 1");
}
```

If an exception happens anywhere those messages boxes are shown which is great, the problem is right after it shows the message the application still crashes. If I run the application in debug, Visual Studio will jump to the place were the exception happened and if I continue it will then go to the message box.

I think the problem has something to do with that but I am not sure. Is there a way to catch the exception like I am above but at the same time not have the application crash after?

Thank You

**EDIT**
The exceptions that get through to the UnhandledException section will be things like NullReference, NotSupported or Database Exceptions for the most park. If a "serious" exception gets cought like Stack Overflow I will simple notify the user and kill the app. I still need to find a way to stop the app from crashing on non serious exceptions though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need to set

```
dispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Handled = true;
```

Comment: unhandledExceptionEventArgs has no Handled property :(

Comment: @Firo, [Bryan Cook's article on unhandled exceptions](http://www.bryancook.net/2013/07/unhandled-exceptions-in-wpf-applications.html) may explain why. "If your code reaches this event handler it is completely unrecoverable... The only way to prevent the dialog is to use Environment.Exit(1);"

Comment: The answer is incorrect as unhandledExceptionEventArgs  does not have the Handled property. The solution is to catch exception that has been thrown on the background (worker) thread and then to re-throw it on the main thread (most likely UI thread). Once re-throw it will be handled in the DispatcherOnUnhandledException event handler.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of exception is your application catching? Using UnhandledException for exceptions that change state will not work unless you are setting HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute  attribute.

```
From MSDN documentation:
AppDomain.UnhandledException Event
```

Starting with the .NET Framework 4, this event is not raised for exceptions that corrupt the state of the process, such as stack overflows or access violations, unless the event handler is security-critical and has the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Comment: The exceptions that get through to the UnhandledException section will be things like NullReference, NotSupported or Database Exceptions. If a "serious" exception gets cought like Stack Overflow I will simple notify the user and kill the app. So I need to find a way to stop the app from crashing on non serious exceptions.